# How can I move data to map?

Tags: apex, map

I have data in a map mymap which is `map<string,event> x`, i want to move this data to another map yourmap which is `map<string,list<event>`.  How to accomplish this?

```
Map<String, Event> myMap = new Map<String, Event>();
Map<String, list<Event>> yourMap = new Map<String, list<Event>>();
for (eve:elist){
 for ( integer i = 0; i <= days; i++){
       DateTime DT = e.StartDateTime + i;
       string newdate = DT.formatgmt('MM/dd/YYYY');
       myMap.put(newdate, eve);
 }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to be more specific about what data you need in your second list? Are you trying to seperate the events into a map by the date they occured?

Comment: yes thats correct i want the events to move from this mymap to yourmap as yourmap is the master map which has other data too

Answer (score 2):

If you want to group the `Event` records by the `Date` of their `StartDateTime`, you can do so with an approach something like the following:

```
Map<Date, List<Event>> startDateToEvents = new Map<Date, List<Event>>();
for (Event record : myMap.values())
{
    Date start = record.StartDateTime.date();
    if (!startDateToEvents.containsKey(start))
        startDateToEvents.put(start, new List<Event>());
    startDateToEvents.get(start).add(record);
}
```

If you want to map a range of `Date` values to each record, it would be just a minor adjustment. Something like:

```
Date start = record.StartDateTime.date();
for (Integer offset = 0; offset < days; offset++)
{
    Date adjustedStart = start.addDays(offset);
    if (!startDateToEvents.containsKey(adjustedStart))
        startDateToEvents.put(adjustedStart, new List<Event>());
    startDateToEvents.get(adjustedStart).add(record);
}
```

It should be straightforward enough to adjust these approaches for `String` keys, but I advise using `Date`. Better to use strong typing where you can.

Comment: i just want to move from one type of map to another map.  the last loop throws error. Map<String, Event> myMap = new Map<String, Event>();
Map<String, list<Event>> yourMap = new Map<String, list<Event>>();
for (eve:elist){
 for ( integer i = 0; i <= days; i++){
       DateTime DT = e.StartDateTime + i;
       string newdate = DT.formatgmt('MM/dd/YYYY');
       myMap.put(newdate, eve);
 }  for (string d: mymap.keyset()){
                              yourmap.put(d,mymap.get(d));
                          }

Comment: Yes this answer explains how you can move to `Map<Date, List<Event>>` and can be easily adapted to instead move to `Map<String, List<Event>>`.